# Biopython search based on accession number

Tags: python, biopython

Currently I am using biopython to loop over an list with accession numbers to retrieve some information about the proteins. I would like to check the isoelectric point, Amino acid composition,Theoretical pI, Number of amino acids and the Molecular weight. Some of those properties I can find, but for some I don't know how to get them. Hopefully somebody can help me.

Please find a summary of my code below:

```
from bio import ExPASy, SwissProt

accession='P04264'
handle = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw(accession)
record = SwissProt.read(handle)

Sequence_length=record.sequence_length
Weight= record.seqinfo[1]
```

As you can see, I figured out how to get the sequence length and the weight, but I did not manage to get the other properties (isoelectric point, Amino acid composition,Theoretical pI). Does somebody know how to get those values, using bioptyhon?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isoelectric point information appears to be absent for the protein you provided as a [demo](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04264). Perhaps other records contain that information, but you'll have to search for it. Instructions for Bio.SwissProt.Record decoding can be found [here](https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SwissProt.Record-class.html). You can get sequence length and weight using `record.seqinfo`. The protein sequence can be found with `record.sequence`. You should be able to calculate a theoretical isoelectric point using the protein sequence. There are [online tools](https://web.expasy.org/compute_pi/) that will do the calculation for you.